# Element is found in XPath Checker but not in Selenium

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, xpath

I have the following XPath:

```
//div[contains(@id, 'box')]/div/h4/small/a[contains(@href, 'google')]/@href
```

When I try out this XPath in XPath Checker (Firefox extension), it works perfectly all the time. But when I do the following in Selenium:

```
System.out.println(selenium.getAttribute("//div[contains(@id, 'box')]/div/h4/small/a[contains(@href, 'google')]/@href"));
```

It keeps giving me the following log error:

```
14:30:56.311 INFO - Got result: OK on session 5a1401d374a04779bbe6f7fe9a0b4536
14:30:56.315 INFO - Command request: getAttribute[//div[contains(@id, 'box')]/div/h4/small/a[contains(@href, 'google')]/@href, ] on session 5a1401d374a04779bbe6f7fe9a0b4536
14:30:56.372 INFO - Got result: ERROR: Element //div[contains(@id, 'box')]/div/h4/small/a[contains(@href, 'google')]/ not found on session 5a1401d374a04779bbe6f7fe9a0b4536
```

I am going crazy to solve this problem. Does anyone see any mistake that I have in my code line?

Comment: Are you using Selenium RC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't that query string look like this (according to javadoc api)?

```
"xpath=//div[contains(@id, 'box')]/div/h4/small/a[contains(@href, 'google')]/@href"
```

Comment: Selenium should know that this is an xpath locator because it starts with `//`. I would have suspected the `/` before the final `@href`

Comment: Default locators in Selenium http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html#default-locators

Answer (score 2):

According to the [API doc](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html), it should be

```
...getAttribute("xpath=//div[contains....
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot... I guess I'm on too much of caffeine!

Answer (score 1):

In Selenium RC: it needs to mention xpath as "xpath=//div[contains(@id, 'box')]/div/h4/small/a[contains(@href, 'google')]/@href". So in your case, the code is as below:

```
selenium.getAttribute("xpath=//div[contains(@id, 'box')]/div/h4/small/a[contains(@href, 'google')]/@href");
```

In Selenium WebDriver: the code is as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'box')]/div/h4/small/a[contains(@href, 'google')]/@href")).getAttribute("The name of the attribute");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write xpath first
eg

```
WebDriver_Object_name.findElement(By.xpath("...xpath...")).getAttribute("..Attri_name..");
```

Here your `WebDriver_Object_name` might be selenium