# XPath / Selenium can't locate an element using a partial id with contains / start-with

Tags: xpath, selenium

I have the following HTML generated with an AjaxFormLoop.

```
<div id="phones">
    <div class="t-forminjector tapestry-forminjector" id="rowInjector_13b87fdd8b6">
        <input id="number_13b87fdd8b6" name="number_13b87fdd8b7" type="text"/>
        <a id="removerowlink_13b87fdd8b6" href="#" name="removerowlink_13b87fdd8b6">remove</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="t-forminjector tapestry-forminjector" id="rowInjector_13b87fdda70" style="background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 251);">
        <input id="number_13b87fdda70" name="number_13b87fdda70" type="text" />
        <a id="removerowlink_13b87fdda70" href="#" name="removerowlink_13b87fdda70">remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to access the second input field in child 2 using a partial ID, however I have not been successful in getting this to work.

What I've tried thus far.

```
String path = "//input[contains(@id,'number_')][2]";
String path = "(//input[contains(@id,'number_')])[2]";
```

I can't even access input 1 using 1 instead of 2, however if I remove [2] and only use

> String path = "//input[contains(@id,'number_')]";

I'm able to access the first field without issue.

If I use the exact id, I'm able to access either field without issue.

I do need to use the id if possible as there is many more fields in each t-forminjector row that are not present in this example.

**Implementation with Selenium.**

```
    final String path = "(//input[starts-with(@id,'quantity_')])[2]";
    
    new Wait() {
        @Override
        public boolean until() {
            return isElementPresent(path);
        }
    }.wait("Element should be present", TIMEOUT);
```

---

#### Resolved

I'm noticing I can't seem to use the following starts-with / contains to locate any element within to dom, however if I use a complete id, it works.

```
//Partial ID - fails
//*[starts-with(@id,"quantity_")]

//Exact ID - works
//*[starts-with(@id,"quantity_-112409575185705")]
```

Comment: Your 2nd XPath looks correct. It selects `input` with `id="number_13b87fdda70"`

Comment: Smells of an incompliant/buggy XPath implementation. Your second XPath expression is correct. A more precise expression is: `(//input[starts-with(@id, 'number_')])[2]`

Comment: @Dimitree Novatchev, I changed my xpath to use starts-with, still no success. I'm using this with selenium, so I posted my code above. I know the elements are making the dom do to the fact I'm able to print them out with selenium's getHtmlSource method and build a list of field id's from selenium's getAllFields() method and then access them with xpath //input[@id='number_2308423']. This leads me to believe I'm either using xpath incorrectly or there is a bug in it.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev is right. Use something like http://www.xpathtester.com/ to run a quick test.

Comment: @Lwburk, I posted an example with the generated code from the application. Perhaps you guys will be able to help point out my issue. http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/73f39fd7-f240-4e41-bd88-527cc8a8789a

Comment: Is it possible your code is generating variable IDs? That might explain it.

Comment: the root of my id's are defined by me, number, quantity etc. When a new item is injected into the html, the framework appends a random _number to the end of it to keep them unique. I posted the entire generated html xpathtester.com/saved/1ceb98bb-0ab6-40a7-ae05-2c197b5e0573 I'm at a lost as I don't understand why this isn't working :/

Answer (score 0):

The generated output [you pasted here](http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/73f39fd7-f240-4e41-bd88-527cc8a8789a) simply does not contain the string `number_` anywhere in it. It *does* contain `Number_` -- note the capital `N` -- but it's not the first part of the string. Perhaps you meant something like this (which at least selects *something*):

```
(//input[contains(@id, 'Number_')])[2]
```

Or:

```
(//input[starts-with(@id,'catalogNumber_')])[2]
```

Comment: I started my question with a simple phone example in order to simplify the problem. Since that hasn't helped to clarify the issue, I setup a real much more complex test case. I've tried both of your solutions without success.

Comment: @George - I ran it against the content you posted at that link and it worked just fine.

Comment: Yes, I can get it to work against that test page too, however if I try to run it in the actual application, exact code, but nested within the rest of the form I get an error, locator not found. Same error occurs in both the IDE and firefox selenium addon. I'm using selenium 2.14.0, so I'm not sure what verson of xpath is being used. I'm able to find the element using "css=div#lineItem div.t-forminjector:nth-of-type(2) input.quantity", but not the most elegant solution. What do you think might be going on here?

Comment: Could be a namespace issue. Are namespaces defined earlier in the document?

Comment: I just posted the generated html in full. http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/1ceb98bb-0ab6-40a7-ae05-2c197b5e0573 The line item id's are appended to my quantity id with a random _number to make them unique.

Comment: OK, yep, those elements are located in a default namespace -- `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` -- which means you need to associate that namespace with an arbitrary prefix and qualify all element names with that prefix in your XPath expression. This is how the XPath processor knows that those are really the elements you want. Selenium should have some way to do this, but I don't use Selenium, so I can't be much help there.

Answer (score 0):

As Iwburk stated, this was a namespace issue. According to the Selenium API,

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html

while using an xpath expression, I needed to used xpath=xpathExpression changing my query string to:

```
String path = "xpath=(//input[starts-with(@id,'quantity_')])[2]";
```

I found a related post here, 
[Element is found in XPath Checker but not in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711013/xpath-selenium-element-is-found-in-xpath-checker-but-not-in-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

you can't access it because you are not locating the element as to be unique in the page. 
use an xpath that makes it unique , 
- you're xpath look ok .
more info here 
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Besides the selenium syntax problem there's an xpath issue related to markup structure.
xpath 1: `//input[starts-with(@id,'number_')][1]`
xpath 2: `(//input[starts-with(@id,'number_')])[1]`

In the sample below xpath 1 will return 2 nodes (incorrect) and xpath 2 will be correct because `input` nodes are not siblings so surrounding parenthesis are needed to refer to the resulting nodeset

```
<div id="phones">
    <div>
        <input id="number_1" name="number_1" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="number_2" name="number_2" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Result without parenthesis

```
/ > xpath //input[starts-with(@id,'number_')][1]
Object is a Node Set :
Set contains 2 nodes:
1  ELEMENT input
    ATTRIBUTE id
    TEXT
        content=number_1
    ATTRIBUTE name
    TEXT
        content=number_1
    ATTRIBUTE type
    TEXT
        content=text
2  ELEMENT input
    ATTRIBUTE id
    TEXT
        content=number_2
    ATTRIBUTE name
    TEXT
        content=number_2
    ATTRIBUTE type
    TEXT
        content=text
```

In this next sample, parenthesis will not make a difference because nodes are siblings

```
<div id="other">
<input id="pre_1" type="text"/>
<input id="pre_2" type="text" />
<div>a</div>
</div>
```

With parenthesis

```
/ > xpath (//input[starts-with(@id,'pre_')])[1]
Object is a Node Set :
Set contains 1 nodes:
1  ELEMENT input
    ATTRIBUTE id
    TEXT
        content=pre_1
    ATTRIBUTE type
    TEXT
        content=text
```

Without parenthesis

```
/ > xpath //input[starts-with(@id,'pre_')][1]
Object is a Node Set :
Set contains 1 nodes:
1  ELEMENT input
    ATTRIBUTE id
    TEXT
        content=pre_1
    ATTRIBUTE type
    TEXT
        content=text
```

Testing was done with xmllint shell
`xmllint --html --shell test.html`