# xpath getText() not working in selenium with xpath=

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm using selenium with xpath, I'm trying to get the text of a div within a list. The xpath location should look like this.

```
xpath=(//span[@class='total'])[2]
```

However when I use it like so,

```
getText("xpath=(//span[@class='total'])[2]");
```

I get the following exception:

> ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the user group at
>   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error
>   details from the log window. The error message is: TYPE_ERR: DOM XPath
>   Exception 52

Without the use of xpath=, I can not access my nodes do to namespace issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the HTML making up the `span` element?

Comment: http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/94ddbb6f-3c87-4854-b1e1-4b0a9dad9d06

Comment: @Arran, keep in mind this I have name space issues. I had a very large post yesterday related to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814047/xpath-selenium-cant-locate-an-element-using-a-partial-id-with-contains-star/13829881#13829881

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using? try updating it to the latest

Comment: 2.14.0, unfortunately it's bundled with the Tapestry framework, so I don't know how much control I have over this. Do you think it's an issue for my current version?

Comment: Current version is 2.28.0. Why can't you just give try with that>

Comment: I just posted on the Tapestry forums asking if there is a way for me to do it. I'm not sure how to do this. In later versions, can xpath= be used within these methods?

Comment: @Santoshsarma, I'm now on the latest version and the problem still exist.

Comment: I tried this code as shown here - https://gist.github.com/4273864 and it did return the text correctly. Which browser/version are you using?

Comment: I just wanted to let everyone know it's working. I'm thinking it may of been some sort of caching issue causing it not to work when I did the version upgrade. Thanks Guys.